# How can I verify image URI is valid in Android?

Tags: android, validation, uri

I am building my own contact picker, because I needed multi-select support. Everything is working fine, except for one small problem with the contact images.

For contacts who don't have images I am showing a "no image" image. This works fine for contacts in the phone's address book. I am having a problem however when it comes to images from my google contacts.

Most of my google contacts do not have photos. However, when i query the Contacts database for photos, it still returns a URI for them of the form of `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/657/photo` (which is the same format as for contacts who ***do*** have a photo.

Then when I try to assign the photo to a QuickContactBadge, using `bdg.setImageURI(pic);` it sets it to essentially a blank picture, and logs a silent INFO message stating:

```
INFO/System.out(3968): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/657/photo
```

I need to know how I can either
**a)** validate the URI *or*
**b)** catch the INFO message above
**c)** query the imageview/badge to see if it found a valid image

so that i can assign these contacts my "no image" image.
How can I go about doing this?

**EDIT 20110812.0044**

I have tried adding this to my code as per Laurence's suggestion (which he's since removed):

```
// rv is my URI variable
if(rv != null) {
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(rv.toString());
    if (d == null) rv = null;
}
```

While the google contacts now get my "no image" image, ... so do all the other contacts, including ones that **do** in fact have images.

Comment: Do you know where the contact images are stored on the SDcard/internal memory? Maybe if you could locate the folder, then iterating through all the member you could validate if the selected image exist or not.

Comment: Well, the only URI I get is the `content://com.android.contacts/...` URI mentioned, which is simply referring to a field in the `Contacts2.db` file in the db store. Looking at the PHOTOS view in SQLLite Editor, it looks like the photos are stored directly in the db as raw binary data (the `data` field doesn't show a path, but just shows `(data)`). One of the contacts in question does NOT show `(data)` for their photo, but shows an empty field. Is there somehow I can query the URI to see if it returns NULL?

Comment: The real question is: why are those fake photo records are stored in the database at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to do this after poking through the ImageView source code. It is actually using the QuickContactBadge's own methods, but if necessary, one could always extract [the relevant code from the Badge/ImageView control here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ImageView.java).

After setting the QCB's image, I check to see if its drawable is null, instead of trying my own (as per Laurence's suggestion). This works better, because there is actually a whole slew of checking code the ImageView widget uses.

Here is my final code:

```
bdg.setImageURI(pic);
if(bdg.getDrawable() == null) bdg.setImageResource(R.drawable.contactg);
```

This works perfectly as I was hoping and expecting.

Comment: This is fine, but if you use an Adapter, you can not check this way. So you should check the uri before

Comment: this is really bad, especially when in a grid or list view.

Comment: @Olayinka - care to expound a little more and add to the conversation? "It's bad." doesn't really explain much. How should it be done then?

Comment: @eidylon It's bad because in a list view where multiple items are loaded new bitmaps are created everytime you call `setImageUri` which takes time and memory.

Comment: Well the gridview does actually have a QuickContactBadge in the item template. I would expect of Google that the QCB would reuse the same bitmap. So either way, whether it uses the one from the contact or whether it winds up using my "no image" image, it still is going to be creating a bitmap anyway. I'm not creating a QCB just to test the image.

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but it put me on the right track...  thanks and +1

Comment: @xnagyg funny, i just used this pattern in a recyclerview adapter...  looks like it works to me

Comment: @Olayinka what's to stop you from replacing the URI/PIC in your list when you encounter a null value... like this arrayList.set(position, Uri/drawable/whatever); the next time it comes through the viewholder there is no error...

Answer (score 4):

Just to answer the question on how to check the (data) value in the MediaStore:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA}
Cursor cur = cr.query(Uri.parse(contentUri), projection, null, null, null);
if(cur != null) {
    cur.moveToFirst();
    String filePath = cur.getString(0);

    if (filePath == null || filePath.isEmpty()) {
        // data not set
    } else if((new File(filePath)).exists()){
        // do something if it exists
    } else {
        // File was not found
        // this is binary data
    }
} else {
    // content Uri was invalid or some other error occurred 
}
```

Inspiration taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7649784/621690 and others.

There is also the column `SIZE` that might be checked: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#SIZE
It sounds like it should contain 0 if there is no data value. But I wouldn't know what it contains if data is a file path.

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the images are not downloaded. I faced a similar problem with whatsapp images.
One way to go about this could be like below:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
   is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(myuri);
}catch (Exception e){
   Log.d("TAG", "Exception " + e);
}

if(is==null)
    //Assign to "no image"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ImageView.java) my solution for checking Uri:

> ```
> public static Uri checkUriExists (Context  mContext,Uri mUri) {
>     Drawable d = null;
>     if (mUri != null) {
>         if ("content".equals(mUri.getScheme())) {
>             try {
>                 d = Drawable.createFromStream(
>                         mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri),
>                         null);
>             } catch (Exception e) {
>                 Log.w("checkUriExists", "Unable to open content: " + mUri, e);
>                 mUri = null;
>             }
>         } else {
>             d = Drawable.createFromPath(mUri.toString());
>         }
>
>         if (d == null) {
>             // Invalid uri
>             mUri = null;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return mUri;
> }
> ```

Comment: Its works, but it's too slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function which returns boolean

```
private fun isUriValid(context: Context,uri: Uri):Boolean{
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    return try {
        contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.close()
        true
    } catch (e:Exception){
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I am using this code for Uri that has file:// authority

```
Uri resimUri = Uri.parse(path_str);
File imgFile = new File(resimUri.getPath());
if (imgFile.exists()) {
    // file exists
}else {
    // file is not there
}
```