# Check whether a known document Uri exists in android phone storage

Tags: java, android

I am fetching a document Uri from the server which points out to where the document (pdf or word) was initially stored in the phone storage at the time of upload. In my app, I would want to check if the document still exists in the user's phone storage (by checking if this uri is still valid) before downloading the document. How can I do this?I've tried multiple ways to no success. Please help.
This is what I've already tried.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.providers.downloads.documments/document/748");
            final File f = new File(uri.getPath());
           if (f.exists()){
                Log.d("File existence", "Yes, file exists");
            }else {
                Log.d("File does not exist", "so sorry");
            }
```

I also tried implementing this using ContentResolver as pointed out in  [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645951/how-to-check-if-resource-pointed-by-uri-is-available/43981689) but the method threw a security exception: querying the cursor requires manage documents permission which when added to the manifest also brought an error, that the permission is only used by system apps.
Please help. I'm running the app in android 6.0.1
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just try to open an input stream for the uri. `getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`.

Comment: Of course you cannot use the File class for a content scheme uri.

Comment: But my proposal will only work if you still have a read permission. And you did not tell if you took a persistable permission at upload.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
getContext().getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions().forEach( {element -> element.uri == yourUri});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How do you implement this on Kitkat..coz forEach call requires API24 and above. My min is 19 (KitKat)

Comment: Look for this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42276329/unable-to-use-foreach-and-lambda-in-android-min-sdk-version-less-than-24

Comment: does that helped you?

Comment: not really :(. Could you kindly kindly show a full implementation of this?